# it only writes one letter and exites the loop

Tags: python

i made a simple "Encrypting" code that turns every letter in a string to a specific letter, like
input = CS
"C => 3X, S => 19G"

Output = 3X19G

the encryption works fine, but the problem is with the decryption code below, when i run it, it only prints the first letter then exits the loop or something

```
def decrypt(string):

    decrypted = ""
    decrypt_letter = ""

    for letter in string :

        decrypt_letter += letter

        if decrypt_letter in encryption.values() :

                decrypted +="".join(list(encryption.keys())[list(encryption.values()).index(decrypt_letter)])
                decrypt_letter = ""

    print(decrypted)
```

input = 3X19G

output = "C"

and ignoring the "S" of course

```
encryption = {"A":"1Z","B":"2Y","C":"3X","D":"4W","E":"5V","F":"6T","G":"7S","H":"8R","I":"9Q","J":"10P","K":"11O","L":"12N",
              "M":"13","N":"14L","O":"15K","P":"16J","Q":"17I","R":"18H","S":"19G","T":"20F","U":"21E","V":"22D","W":"23C","X":"24B","Y":"25A",
              "Z":"26","a":"1z","b":"2y","c":"3x","d":"w","e":"5v","f":"6t","g":"7s","h":"8r","i":"9q","j":"10p","k":"11o","l":"12n","m":"13s",
              "n":"14l","o":"15k","p":"16j","q":"17i","r":"18h","s":"19g","t":"20f","u":"21e","v":"22d","w":"23c","x":"24b","y":"25a","z":"26"," ":'\s'}
```

this is the encryption/decryption list

sorry for the code uglieness

Comment: The `decrypt()` function doesn't return anything at all, so it's unclear how you're actually using it.  Please post a **complete** example that actually calls the function.

Comment: Also, where is `letter_r` defined?  Incomplete code like this makes it hard for us to help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset `decrypt_letter` inside the if block after decrypting a letter and iterate over the characters of the encrypted string, not just the letters.

```
def decrypt(string):
    decrypted = ""
    decrypt_letter = ""

    for char in string:
        decrypt_letter += char

        if decrypt_letter in encryption.values():
            decrypted += "".join(list(encryption.keys())[list(encryption.values()).index(decrypt_letter)])
            decrypt_letter = ""

    print(decrypted)
```